# Ionic Cordova splash screen not hiding in Android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I have a simple application which works fine in browser and iOS, however for some reason in Android device and emulator they application stuck in the splash screen and do nothing. No error in the console log. however, in chrome inspector in chrome inspect I can see the application. already looked into google and couldn't find any helpful information.

Already removed and added splash screen plugin.

I am ready to release the but only this one bug is holding me and I am running out of time. Please help

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

On the first page you try to launch the App put splashScreen.hide() to hide the splashScreen manually.

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.platform.is('cordova')  || this.platform.is('android')){
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      }
    }, 300);
```

Also check the config.xml for Splash screen properties like the below

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="1000" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
```

Refer this [link](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/) for property definitions.

> 1. SplashScreenDelay (number, default to 3000). Amount of time in milliseconds to wait before automatically hide splash screen.
> 2. "SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" preference is also optional and defaults to true. When set to true splash screen will only appear on
>      application launch. However, if you plan to use
>      navigator.app.exitApp() to close application and force splash screen
>      appear on next launch, you should set this property to false (this
>      also applies to closing the App with Back button).
> 3. FadeSplashScreenDuration (float, defaults to 500): Specifies the number of milliseconds for the splash screen fade effect to execute.
> 4. FadeSplashScreen (boolean, defaults to true): Set to false to prevent the splash screen from fading in and out when its display
>      state changes.
> 5. ShowSplashScreenSpinner (boolean, defaults to true): Set to false to hide the splash-screen spinner.